# Python 3 64bit - GUI Package

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, package, 64-bit

I have my code in Python3.5 64bit version. I wanted to use the Tkinter package to create a GUI for my application. However, "Tkinter" is compatible with 32-bit version and I could not find any source to solve this problem. Is there any other package to use for GUI development in Python 3 64-bit version?

Comment: why do you think tkinter only works on 32bit python?

Comment: tkinter works with 64bit Python versions. Also, *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: Tkinter comes with both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of Python.  If you are saying it's not compatible you are probably trying to use a script for Python 2 not Python 3.  Try the [3.5 Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tk.html) and see if their examples work.  If you are getting an error edit your question to include the script and the errors you got.